# Why is the derivative of the bounded variation nonnegative definite?

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

The following is from a proof I am reading.

Let $C=((c_{ij}))$ be a continuous, symmetric, $d\times d$ matrix-valued function, defined on $[0,\infty)$, satisfying $C(0)=0$ and
$$\sum(c_{ij}(t)-c_{ij}(s))\xi_i\xi_j\geq0\text{, }\xi\in \mathbb R^d\text{, }t>s\geq0.$$

Set
$$\gamma(t)=\sum_{i=1}^d c_{ii}(t)$$
by take $\xi_i=1$ and $\xi_j=0$ otherwise for each $i$, I know $\gamma(t)$ is increasing continuous function. By take $xi_i=1$, $\xi_j=\pm 1$, and $\xi_l=0$ otherwise, 
$$|c_{ij}(t)-c_{ij}(s)|\leq\gamma(t)-\gamma(s)$$
hence $c_{ij}$ is of bounded variation and $c_{ij}$ can be written as
$$c_{ij}(t)=\int_0^t d_{ij}(s)d\gamma(s)$$

My question is why it can conclude $D(s)=((d_{ij}(s)))$ is nonnegative definite? Thanks very much!

Comment: i'm not really sure i understand how you define $d_{ij}$.

Comment: @Renart I think $d_{ij}$ is the a.e. derivative of $c_{ij}$, since $c_{ij}$ is bounded variation. The proof said no more than I write here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $a<b$ two real numbers.

$\displaystyle \sum(c_{ij}(b)-c_{ij}(a))\xi_i\xi_j\geq0 \Longleftrightarrow   \sum \int_a^b d_{ij}(s)\xi_i\xi_j\mathrm d\gamma (s) \geq 0 \Longleftrightarrow  \int_a^b \sum d_{ij}(s)\xi_i\xi_j\mathrm d\gamma (s) \geq 0$

Since $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary we can deduce that $\sum d_{ij}(s)\xi_i\xi_j$ is positive $\mathrm d \gamma(s)$-almost everywhere. This is a classical result from integration theory. Since $\xi$ was also arbitrary $(d_{ij}(s))$ is nonnegative semidefinite almost everywhere (for $\mathrm d \gamma (s))$.

Note that if $\gamma$ is constant on $[a,b]$ then $\mathrm d \gamma (s)$ is identically zero on $[a,b]$ and $(d_{ij}(s))$ can be wathever you want(even a negative definite matrix).

However $(d_{ij})$ does not need to be nonnegative **definite**. One can have (for fixed $a$ and $b$) $C(b)-C(a)$ to be non zero, nonnegative semidefinite but not nonnegative definite and with $\gamma(b)-\gamma(a)>0$. Plus you can find $C$ satifsfying all that plus the fact that there exists a non-zero $\xi$ such that $(C(t)\xi,\xi)=0$ for all $t\in[a;b]$. Then $\mathrm d \gamma$ is not zero on $[a;b]$ and $\displaystyle \sum(c_{ij}(b)-c_{ij}(a))\xi_i\xi_j=0$ so $(D(t))$ is only nonnegative semidefinite $\mathrm d \gamma$ almost everywhere and not definite.

Comment: I get it. Thank you very much!

Comment: i added something about the definite part (which was your original question). If you want nonnegative definiteness then you should assume the first inequality of your question to be a strict inequality. If  you don't take a strict inequality $(d_{ij}(s))$ won't be definite ine general.

Comment: Sorry but I am a little confused. As I knew nonnegative definite (it just need $\geq$ 0) may be the same as nonnegative semidefinite as you mean.

Comment: Okay maybe i'm not using the common usual definitions in english. By "a matrix A is nonnegative definite" i meant $(A\xi;\xi)>0$ for every nonzero $\xi$. And by "A is nonnegative semidefinite" i meant $(A\xi;\xi)\geq 0$ for every $\xi$. Sorry for the confusion, i have trouble with english conventions sometimes...

Comment: Never mind. Thank you all the same! You have helped me a lot.